# My boyfriend and I found this Object on the beach wondering if anyone could help

Tags: species-identification, microbiology

[image]

[image]

My boyfriend and I found this object on the beach and need help Identifying it. It looks like a Shark Tooth not for sure. Found in Gulfshore Alabama on the beach. It looked rusty when we found it but after cleaning it up this is what we ended up with. It is 5 1/2" it feels hollow inside.

Comment: it could a shark tooth but to get a better guess of what it may be could you post the size and where you found it.
Judging on how it looks it may not be a shark tooth as usually they keep there shape throughout being in the sea.

Comment: My best guess is that it is fairly heavily oxidized iron - probably not a tooth, but I can't be sure.

Comment: 5 1/2" is massive - would have to be *Charcharodon megalodon* for that size, which would be fossil. Great whites up to 3" apparently.

Comment: Looks non biological to me. Definitely not shark tooth

Comment: I ran a Metal Detector over it and it Doesn't show up any Metal